# Vuejs on Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I tried to write a Basic vue script but it somehow does not work in my larave blade template.

I get this error:

> app.js:32753 [Vue warn]: Property or method "message" is not defined
> on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this
> property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based
> components, by initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> (found in )

The Code so far:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div id="foo">
      @{{ message }}
    </div>

@endsection

@section('javascript')
    <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#foo',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Can't see what's wrong maybe you have already defined a vue instance elsewhere and it's looking for message in that instance.

Comment: Where is your vue.js file imported. Place it before writing vue insurance

Answer (score 0):

Can't see what's wrong. so the problem is probably with this code

```
@section('javascript')
    <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#foo',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })
    </script>
@endsection
```

You might not have `yield('javascript')` at your layouts/app.blade.php

Comment: Hi I defnied another vue instance but with a different Name is that not allowed?

Comment: It is allowed but It should have a different element. el: '#different'

Answer (score -1):

`data` should be a function that returns an object.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#foo',
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  }
})
```

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-data-essential